# Closure with Box<T> arguments in Rust

Tags: rust

I want to know how to code Closure(function) with Box argument in Rust.

For just , it's simple.

```
fn main() {
    let a = 5;
    let double = |x| 2 * x;
    let b = double(a); //10
}
```

now, for Box

```
fn main() {
    let a = Box::new(5);
    let double = |x| 2 * x; //how to write?
    let b = double(a);
}
```

I don't know what is the adequate or smart way to code, and for unknown reason, the official document or Google did not help.

Please advise.

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with closures – you can’t write `let b = 2 * a;` either, and the solution `let b = 2 * (*a);` is the same.

Comment: Ok, however, as you can see the accepted answer, the extra information 'need to specify the closure parameter type in this case' is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how you can do that:

```
fn main() {
    let a = Box::new(5);
    let double = |x: Box<i32>| 2 * *x;
    let b = double(a);
    print!("{b}")
}
```

First, you need to specify the closure parameter type in this case. Instead of `Box<i32>`, you can also write `Box<_>`.

Next, you need to get the value owned by the `Box` via `*x`.